# OpenGL/GLM 3D model texturing issue

Tags: opengl

I am using OpenGL, GLM, ILU and GLUT libraries for loading and texturing 3D models. The models appear to load in correctly, however when it comes to the texturing the texture seems to repeat.

I have included two pictures below showing non-textured, textured.

**non-textured**:

[image]

**textured**:

[image]

If you look closely enough to the last image, the texture is applied to a tiny scale and repeated across the whole model.

For the code, I first start by loading the texture.

```
ILboolean success = false;

if (ilGetInteger(IL_VERSION_NUM) < IL_VERSION)
{
    return false;
}

ilInit();  /*Initialize the DevIL library*/
ilGenImages(1, &ilTextureID); //Generate DevIL image objects
ilBindImage(ilTextureID); /* Binding of image object */
success = ilLoadImage((const ILstring)theFilename); /* Loading of image*/

if (!success)
{
    ilDeleteImages(1, &ilTextureID);
    return false;
}

success = ilConvertImage(IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE); // Convert every colour component into unsigned byte.
if (!success)
{
    return false;
}

textureWidth = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
textureHeight = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);

glGenTextures(1, &GLTextureID); // GLTexture name generation 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLTextureID); // Binding of GLtexture name 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // Use linear interpolation for magnification filter
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); // Use linear interpolation for minifying filter 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP), ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH),
    ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT), 0, ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_FORMAT), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    ilGetData()); /* Texture specification */
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLTextureID); // Binding of GLtexture name 

ilDeleteImages(1, &ilTextureID);
```

I have tried things like adding,

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

but this just seems to make the model non-textured.

Then I call the method to model loading method and apply the texture:

```
m_model = glmReadOBJ(mdlFilename);
glmFacetNormals(m_model);
glmVertexNormals(m_model, 180.0f, false);
m_TextureID = mdlTexture.getTexture();
m_model->textures[m_model->numtextures - 1].id = m_TextureID;
m_model->textures[m_model->numtextures - 1].width = mdlTexture.getTWidth();
m_model->textures[m_model->numtextures - 1].height =mdlTexture.getTHeight();
```

For the above code, whilst I was debugging I am getting negative values for 
"vertices", "normals" and "facetnorms" for the 3D model, but I am getting values for "numnormals", "numtexcoords" and "numfacetnorms". I'm not entirely sure if this is normal.

And finally for the rendering of the model:

```
glPushMatrix();
//transformations here...
glTranslatef(mdlPosition.x, 0.0f, -mdlPosition.z);
glRotatef(mdlRotationAngle, 0, 1, 0);
glScalef(mdlScale.x, mdlScale.y, mdlScale.z);
glmDraw(m_model, GLM_SMOOTH | GLM_TEXTURE | GLM_MATERIAL);  
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Which GLM?  [This one](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/)?

Comment: I am using glm-0.3.2

Comment: @Gary: He's asking if you mean GLM-the-mesh-library or GLM-the-math-library.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using both

Comment: Looks like a problem with the texture coordinates for me. Can you check if they are correct?

Comment: Texture coordinates should usually be in range [0; 1], are you sure you have them set properly?